# Joomla: Problems when migrating from PHP 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: php, joomla

My hoster will stop supporting PHP 5.2 in a few weeks, which is why I have to switch to PHP 5.3. I'm using Joomla 2.5 to manage the content of a site. In the backend of the hoster, I switched to the new PHP version with the click of a button, but that made the site crash with the error below.

Apparently, my code is not ready for PHP 5.3. How can I update the joomla code to the new PHP? Or should joomla handle the new PHP version without a problem and something I added actually causes the error? The only code that is from me is the template that loads a custom design.

I'm kind of stuck here and don't really see the connection between joomla, PHP and also how the hoster backend new that I was using an old PHP. Any suggestions whould be appreciated....

---

The error. Note: this is copied from another site, I loaded a backup to fix the error on my site, but apart from the paths it was exactly the same:

```
jos-Error: Application Instantiation Error

JFactory :: getApplication() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/index.php:28
JApplication :: getInstance() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/factory.php:102
JSite -> __construct() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/application/application.php:208
JApplication -> __construct() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/includes/application.php:48
JApplication -> _createSession() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/application/application.php:173
JFactory :: getSession() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/application/application.php:1046
JFactory :: createSession() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/factory.php:152
JSession :: getInstance() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/factory.php:661
JSession -> __construct() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/session/session.php:155
JSession -> _start() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/session/session.php:118
session_start() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/session/session.php:492
JSessionStorageDatabase -> read()
JFactory :: getDbo() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/session/storage/database.php:67
JFactory :: createDbo() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/factory.php:308
JError :: raiseError() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/factory.php:723
JError :: raise() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:251
JError :: throwError() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:176
call_user_func_array() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:214
JError :: handleMessage()
JFactory :: getApplication() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:705
JError :: raiseError() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/factory.php:99
JError :: raise() @ /home/parolevo/public_html/tiptopart/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:251
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the [technical requirements page for Joomla!](http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html) version 2.5 recommends PHP 5.3.

I can also confirm that all of our (+ client) 2.5 sites run on PHP 5.3 without problem so, the only conclusion is that it's something you've added to the base install or changed in the *core* Joomla! code.

Looking at the error log isn't very helpful but I can tell you that it's appears to be having a problem connecting to the database. I would check your `configuration.php` file for possible issues - confirm that the database & connection type settings are correct.

Comment: It actually was the configuration file! Thanks so much... What I did was to let the hoster back-end create a fresh joomla installation for me, and from there I copied the parts in the configuration file that were different in mine. I'm not entierly sure what was wrong, but now it works.